# Vercel build failing on Next.js 14 with app router?

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

I just went to deploy a nextjs project to vercel, and encountered this error:

```js
    > Build error occurred
    Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1258:15
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      type: 'Error'
    }
    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

This initially happened in my /api/auth/[...next-auth] route, but I removed the file to see if that was the issue. One by one, it kept erroring out for every file in the /app/api directory.

I tried adding the following as per another post related to this:

```js
    export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
    export const fetchCache = "force-no-store";
```

But that didn't work. I saw another solution that said to upgrade to node 16, but I'm running 20 and this did not solve it either.

No builds have failed locally, and I've never had this issue before either.

I'm not sure that it's related to next-auth at all, but here is what the route.ts file looks like:

```js
    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
    import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
    import { authOptions } from "@/lib/authOptions";
    import { RouteHandlerContext } from "@/types/authTypes";
    
    const auth = async (req: NextRequest, context: RouteHandlerContext) => {
        return await NextAuth(req, context, authOptions(context));
    }
    
    export { auth as GET, auth as POST };
```

I also have environment variables already for NEXTAUTH_URL and NEXTAUTH_SECRET.

I haven't gotten an error for any page in the app router either, it seems to be only those found in /api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well.. For anyone that has this issue in the future:

I first updated the package.json file to run the prisma command on build:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
```

And secondly when creating the project, I forgot to delete the default folder that was made for the project with create-next-app after I moved it to the root directory of the repository. This was the main issue, however prisma was also throwing an error during builds.